# "ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null" when I spawn a shader in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I work with Unity3D (2020.3.26f1), MRTK and Hololens2.

In my case I have a unity scene that contains a button. If the user clicks the button, an image should be taken via the HoloLens 2 webcam and displayed in the scene. I used the code from the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/windowsholographic-photocapture.html) (this works better for me than the microsoft documentation).

If I deploy the code below to the HoloLens 2, start the app and click the button that is supposed to take the picture, nothing happens. I added the script correctly.

For debugging reasons, I then connected my webcam to the computer and started the Unity scene. Now when I click the button in the game window, the console shows me the following error:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: shader

The error is referring to line 44:

> quadRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Custom/Unlit/UnlitTexture"));

I can't figgure out the problem maybe someone can help here.

This is the code im Using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;
using UnityEngine.Windows.WebCam;

public class PhotoCaptureExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
    Texture2D targetTexture = null;

    // Use this for initialization
    public void TakePhoto()
    {
        Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
        targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

        // Create a PhotoCapture object
        PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate (PhotoCapture captureObject) {
            photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
            CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();
            cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
            cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

            // Activate the camera
            photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(cameraParameters, delegate (PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result) {
                // Take a picture
                photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
            });
        });
    }

    void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
    {
        // Copy the raw image data into the target texture
        photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);

        // Create a GameObject to which the texture can be applied
        GameObject quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
        Renderer quadRenderer = quad.GetComponent<Renderer>() as Renderer;
        quadRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Custom/Unlit/UnlitTexture"));

        quad.transform.parent = this.transform;
        quad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);

        quadRenderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", targetTexture);

        // Deactivate the camera
        photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
    }

    void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
    {
        // Shutdown the photo capture resource
        photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
        photoCaptureObject = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like `Shader.Find("Custom/Unlit/UnlitTexture")` returns `null` .... could you show us your shader code?

Comment: as I understand it, the shader is created via the code and contains the picture made by the hololens or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: No the shader has to already exist in your project. The code tries to find it by name/path .. an apparently doesn't find it

Comment: Right that makes sense... Thank you. So the easiest way to display the Image would be to use a default shader like "Legacy Shaders/Diffuse"?

Comment: Either that or you simply reference an existing shader in a `public Shader shader;` or even better: Make sure you already have a `Material` you can use / copy this would also ensure that this specific shader isn't stripped of during the build process.

Comment: You would recommend creating a ```material``` especially for the images that are to be displayed, to which I then simply attach the image?

Comment: exactly. By doing this it should actually create a copy / instance of this material so even for multiple objects this should work

Comment: Alright. I've tried this now with a standard shader and when I capture the image in the unity game window with a webcam everything works now. Now when I run the code on the Hololens 2 and click the button to take a picture, nothing happens. Do you have any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Maybe that standard shader is stripped of during the build since it is nowhere really referenced as mentioned ... check the ProjectSettings -> Graphics and add your shader to the "Always include Shaders` list

Comment: It is already included. I think the camera is not initialized because the hololens isnt askin for camera permission as it does usual however camera and microphone is activated in user settings.

Comment: If you are concerned about the camera does not work, you can add a breakpoint on OnCapturedPhotoToMemory method to check the state of the photoCaptureFrame property, for how to attach Debugger to UWP App already running on HoloLens2, please refer to his doc: [Debugging an installed or running app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2#debugging-an-installed-or-running-app)